# Fourier series for $e^{-|x|}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

So I'm trying to find the Fourier series of the $PC_{2\pi}$ function $e^{-|x|}$ for $x\in[-\pi,\pi]$ using the formula

$$c_0+\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty c_k e^{-ikx}$$

where

$$
c_k(f)=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)e^{-ikx} dx
$$
I've reached an answer (below), but I think that the result is wrong.  Is my answer correct? If not, then what is the correct answer?

---

In this case that would be finding

$$c_k(f)=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{-|x|}e^{-ikx} dx$$

which I've separated into

$$=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^0 e^{x-ikx} dx + \int_0^\pi e^{-x-ikx}dx $$

For each of them I found

\begin{align}
\int_{-\pi}^{0} e^{x-i k x} d x &= \int e^{t} \cdot \frac{1}{1-i k} d t \\
&= \int \frac{e^{t}(1+i k)}{1+k^{2}} d t \\
&= \int \frac{e^{t}}{1+k^{2}}+i \frac{k e^{t}}{1+k^{2}} d t \\
&= \int_{-\pi}^{0} \frac{e^{x-i k x}}{1+k^{2}} d t+\int_{-\pi}^{0} i \frac{k e^{x-i k x}}{1+k^{2}} d t \\
&=\frac{1-e^{-\pi+i \pi k}}{1+k^{2}}+\frac{i k}{1+k^{2}}\left(1-e^{-\pi+i \pi k}\right)
\end{align}

and

\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\pi} e^{-x-i k x} d x &= \int e^{t} \cdot \frac{1}{-1-i k} d t \\
&= \int \frac{e^{t}(-1+i k)}{1+k^{2}} d t \\
&= \int-\frac{e^{t}}{1+k^{2}}+i \frac{k e^{t}}{1+k^{2}} d t \\
&= \int_{0}^{\pi}-\frac{e^{-x-i k x}}{1+k^{2}} d t+\int_{-\pi}^{0} i \frac{k e^{-x-i k x}}{1+k^{2}} d t \\
&=\frac{e^{-\pi-i \pi k}-1}{1+k^{2}}+i \frac{k}{1+k^{2}}\left(e^{-\pi-i \pi k}-1\right)
\end{align}

Hence my final result:
$$ c_k(f)= \frac{e^{i\pi k}+e^{-\pi-i\pi k}+ike^{-\pi-i\pi k}-ike^{i\pi k-\pi}}{2\pi(1+k^2)}$$

Answer (score 1):

The Fourier cosine series for $e^{-\left|x\right|}$ is as follows.

**(1)** $\quad e^{-\left|x\right|}=\frac{1+\sinh (\pi )-\cosh(\pi)}{\pi}+\frac{2}{\pi}\underset{K\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\ \sum\limits_{k=1}^K \frac{\left(1-(-1)^k e^{-\pi }\right)}{k^2+1}\cos(k\ x)$

---

Figure (1) below illustrates formula (1) above for $e^{-\left|x\right|}$ evaluated at $K=100$ in orange overlaid on the blue reference function.

---

[image: Illustration of formula (1)]

**Figure (1)**: Illustration of formula (1) for $e^{-\left|x\right|}$

---

The following links provide information on the derivation of Fourier cosine series for even functions.

---

[Wikipedia: Cosine series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_sine_and_cosine_series#Cosine_series)

[Weisstein, Eric W. "Fourier Cosine Series." From MathWorld--A Wolfram Web Resource.](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierCosineSeries.html)